# Debugging OpenCV matrices in GDB, C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, matrix, gdb

I am trying to view Opencv Matrices while debugging in gdb.

I tried using this script [cv_imshow.py](https://github.com/renatoGarcia/gdb-imshow).

First when sourcing `import Image` did not work. It failed because gdb uses python 3 which did not have PIL or Pillow.

Then I installed Pillow for Python 3: 
`pip3 install Pillow`

Then replace the `import Image` with: 
`from PIL import Image`

The remaining problem is to convert cv_imshow.py from python 2 to python 3.

Here is what I did:

```
- return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size)) 
+ return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
```

Also replaced `unicode` with `str`

However when I type

```
(gdb) source /home/user/gdb-imshow/cv_imshow.py 
(gdb) cv_imshow img_color
```

I get the following error:

```
CV_8U with 3 channels, 512 rows and 512 cols 
Python Exception <class 'typeerror'=""> argument must be a sequence:     
Error occurred in Python command: argument must be a sequence
```

How to fix this bug? Make this script compatible with python 3?

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 
GDB 7.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't the first one, trying to use this script for python 3. Have you checked [this](https://github.com/cuekoo/GDB-ImageWatch)?

Comment: Please avoid providing just a link and try to at least post more information on the solution. The link my disappear at some point making your answer (?) invalid. Also the format of your answer is more of a comment.

Comment: Brilliant. Just in case someone runs into the same error with Tkinter: `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`